# Dúvida com leitura de dados de uma web api usando o AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Tenho uma web api feita no asp.net, tenho um script que faz a leitura destes dados, mais estou com dúvida de como fazer os demais métodos.
Estou postando o código do script é do html que no momento esta funcionando apenas o GET. Agradeço

Dúvida: Existe um método $scope.$getAll
onde eu gostaria de enviar um parâmetro para a consulta, este não está funcionando.

Você pode baixar os arquivos aqui:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-svO0-4L_-NZF9pWFVwV3p4Wms&usp=sharing

```html
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var numeros = angular.module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, $log) {



        var sucessoCalBack = function (response) {
            $scope.detalhes = response.data;
        };

        var erroCalBack = function (response) {
            $scope.error = response.data;
        };


        //assim funciona, passando o parametro direto 
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            params: { idusuario: 5 },
            url: 'http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/5'})
             .then(sucessoCalBack,erroCalBack);
        });


        $scope.$getAll = function (idusuario) {
            var config = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/' + idusuario
            };
            $http(config).then(sucessoCalBack, erroCalBack);
        };



})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap-->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>


</head>


<body ng-controller="myController">

            <div class="container">
                <br><br>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>idjogodetalhe</th>
                            <th>nJogo</th>
                            <th>valor</th>
                            <th>total</th>
                            <th>idusuario</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="success" ng-repeat="detalhe in detalhes" >
                            <td>{{detalhe.idjogodetalhe}}</td>
                            <td>{{detalhe.nJogo}}</td>
                            <td>{{detalhe.valor}}</td>
                            <td>{{detalhe.total}}</td>
                            <td>{{detalhe.idusuario}}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

         <button class="btn btn-primary  " data-ng-click="getAll(5)" >Listar Dados</button>    
         <button class="btn btn-primary  " ng-click="post(1245,20.10,20.10,4)" >Adicionar</button>     



            <!--javascript-->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="Script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual exatamente é a sua dúvida? Qual o comportamento esperado por você? Quais são os demais métodos que você está com dificuldade?

Comment: Existe um método $scope.$getAll
onde eu gostaria de enviar um parâmetro para a consulta, este não está funcionando, acredito que se um funcionar os demais métodos também vão funcionar seguindo a mesma lógica.

Comment: Pode exibir a assinatura do seu método no WebApi? Você está usando a annotation [Route] para definir a rota deste método?

Comment: @Vinícius, estou usando o Route, você pode visualizar os dados no navegador:
'http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/webapi/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/5